# Sabre Concurrent request limit

Tags: sabre, sabredav

Does anyone know how many concurrent requests per second can be made to sabre developer bargain finder Max API?

I have searched everywhere and all I can find is contact your rep to have it increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the setup of 50 Sessions included but it was no hard limit. Also we were able to extend it to 150 without any costs. There is as far as i know no limit on concurrent requests but depending on what calls you make, you should have your "look to book ratio" (usually 500:1) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are usually sold in bundles of 50 sessions per EPR but can be increased. I do not believe there is any way of viewing that information about a given EPR in any kind of tool, so your rep is the best place to go for that kind of information. Pricing depends on all sorts of contractual items, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain limit associated with the number of concurrent requests for the API. If the same gets exceeded, you would get the following error :- USG_CONNECTOR_IS_BUSY. This means that the maximum number of concurrent requests for the API has been exceeded. Please contact your Sabre account manager to determine or increase your allocated concurrent request limit for this API.  In this case, wait at least 500 milliseconds and resend the request.

The allocations are usually increased in bundles of 50. Your Sabre account manager would be the best person who can provide specific details.

Answer (score 0):

@PCM7,

There is no specific limit, as this depends on the commercial agreement between the travel agency and Saber, as the token generated for the BFM is managed directly at SABRE.

In the agency where I work we have several tourism companies and with that each one has a specific amount of TPS for BFM.

This information will be obtained directly from the SABER account executive for the travel agency in question.

- https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max